# Am I affected? Heartbleed bug

Tags: server, updates, openssl

I've just learned about the Heartbleed Bug (OpenSSL leaking private keys), and based on the website, heartbleed.com, it says that OpenSSL 1.0.1 through version f is affected. However it leaves off Ubuntu 13.04 off the affected list AND the repositories do not have an update to it.

Let me paste some information here:

```
demortes@vps:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04
Codename:       raring
```

AND

```
demortes@vps:/$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
OpenSSL>
```

I'm seeing that we're not affected even though I have 1.0.1c installed... is this accurate. If not, how can I install OpenSSL 1.0.1g with package management *now*? If it is accurate... why?

Comment: You are running an end-of-life operating system and hence you are not supported.  As per community guidelines, end-of-life operating systems are off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu and as such I have closed the question.

Comment: ... and yes you are affected.  Upgrade to 13.10 now because this bug and many others also affect your o/s.

Comment: For those that might come across this: ISPConfig has released an RC version of ISPConfig 3. Doing an OS upgrade, upgrading ISPConfig 3 and resyncing everything should fix it. Note OpenSSL is still 1.0.1e, but likely patched as seen on another thread.

Comment: See [How to patch CVE-2014-0160 in OpenSSL?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl/444905#444905) — and yes, you are affected if you run any SSL server.

Comment: I am running 13.10, and I just did apt-get update and upgrade, which included openssh, but this only gets me to 1.0.1f -- why is that?

$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Comment: It is completely absurd, given the severity of this issue, to close a question and thus deny help to a large group of people. Unflexible application of guidelines (see definition of "guideline" versus "rule") makes for a really poor community. Please consider re-opening this question.

Comment: @JoshGlover - In closing this I'm just following current community guidance for non-supported versions.  If you wish to discuss this, please create a Meta question.

Comment: I'm in favor of opening this issue. For now, here is my answer in a comment: Download the saucy package from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb (replacing "i386" with "amd64", according to your platform) and install it using `dpkg -i`.

Comment: The thing that stopped me from upgrading was the Apache 2 incompatibility with ISPConfig 3. At the time Heartbleed was announced, ISPConfig 3 had a beta or alpha, and has since released the update. This is no longer for an issue for me. I am now running 14.04 LTS, and should be covered without issue.