# Why unattended-upgrades does not fix heartbleed bug?

Tags: upgrade, openssl, unattended-upgrades

I've followed the instruction to install unattended-upgrades to install automatic security updates on my server (ubuntu server 13.10).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Can you help me to understand why this morning I still have the heartbleed bug on my server ?

```
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Wed Jan  8 20:58:47 UTC 2014
platform: debian-amd64
```

other information:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";

$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log
....
Start-Date: 2014-04-03  15:33:59
Commandline: apt-get install nginx
Install: libxau6:amd64 (1.0.8-1, automatic), libx11-data:amd64 (1.6.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxcb1:amd64 (1.9.1-3ubuntu1, automatic), libvpx1:amd64 (1.2.0-2, automatic), libgd3:amd64 (2.1.0-2, automatic), libxdmcp6:amd64 (1.1.1-1, automatic), libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2, automatic), nginx-common:amd64 (1.4.1-3ubuntu1.3, automatic), nginx:amd64 (1.4.1-3ubuntu1.3), nginx-full:amd64 (1.4.1-3ubuntu1.3, automatic), libx11-6:amd64 (1.6.1-1ubuntu1, automatic), libxpm4:amd64 (3.5.10-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2014-04-03  15:34:02

Start-Date: 2014-04-04  10:26:38
Commandline: apt-get install unattended-upgrades
Install: unattended-upgrades:amd64 (0.79.3ubuntu8)
End-Date: 2014-04-04  10:26:40
```

Thank you

Comment: Not answering your question, but have a look at the answer in this to fix your OS http://askubuntu.com/questions/444817/am-i-affected-heartbleed-bug

Comment: I agree that you should have an updated version. My 12.04 server is on automatic updates and was updated yesterday. Did you check `/var/log/apt/history.log`?

Comment: @jos I had the content of my /var/log/apt/history.log, no more information here

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You do not have the Heartbleed vulnerability on your server, OpenSSL has been patched to fix this issue (without upgrading it).

You have left out several important lines in the OpenSSL version output, that's how you know it's been patched, not with the version number:

```
openssl version -a                                                                ✭
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Apr  7 20:33:19 UTC 2014
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DOPENSSL_NO_TLS1_2_CLIENT -DOPENSSL_MAX_TLS1_2_CIPHER_LENGTH=50 -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

The 'build on' line is what matters here, Apr. 7 or after: you're good. Otherwise: you're in trouble.

Update, since the build date doesn't seem to be good:

Maybe the unattended upgrade hasn't run yet, on my server the scripts in cron.daily are configured to run at 6:25

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

Also, check the contents of /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic and check that security updates are installed:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

Comment: I'm in trouble :( `built on: Wed Jan  8 20:58:47 UTC 2014 platform: debian-amd64`

Comment: just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and you should be up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you @EddTurtle, this is not my question ! My question is why automatic update does not works !

Comment: my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic wasn't good or maybe the cron didn't find any upgrade at 5am. Thank you @mathieu-comandon

Comment: @guillaumevincent I just noticed that unattended-upgrades was the very last package you installed - so it had to be a configuration issue.

Comment: dpkg -l openssl will show you if you have the correct version. For 12.04, if it says "1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12" you are on the fixed version. Note that you will still be vulnerable until you restart any web servers that depend on openssl to ensure they're using the patched version.

Comment: @jos yes sure but I don't know where. I've only run two commands following the official help ubuntu tutorial.

Comment: Is it true that the unattended upgrade didn't work for 13.04 (raring) because it was end-of-lifed a few days before heartbleed happened?

Answer (score 12):

First, you need to perform the upgrade. Unattended-upgrades only runs once a day, and it's been less than 1 day since the fix came out (2014-04-07 around 20:00 GMT). For saucy, make sure that you've upgraded to `libssl1.0.0` version 1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2 or greater. (In precise, the fix came in version 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12.)

Next, note that this is a very bad vulnerability: it may have allowed attackers to obtain confidential data by connecting to your vulnerable server. If you're running an SSL server, then any data that was in the server's memory since a little before the vulnerability was announced may have been leaked. This includes, in particular, the server's SSL private key, so you should generate a new one and revoke the old one.

For more information, see [How to patch the Heartbleed bug (CVE-2014-0160) in OpenSSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl/444905#444905)

Comment: Anything in the server memory for about two years may have been leaked, not just from the time of the announcement.

Comment: @pieroxy Anything that's been in the server's memory for a long time is highly likely to have been overwritten, to the point that you should also worry about many other attack vectors. The exception is if you are worried about adversary who might have known of the bug earlier and exploited it quietly — government-level adversaries might well have known, it's unlikely that ordinary crooks would have.

Answer (score 7):

You can't trust in internal version strings. The version says `1.0.1e` and the bug affects from 1.0.0 through 1.0.0f. Is this enough to determine if you have still a vulnerable version of openssl? No. OpenSSL internal version doesn't change, even trough some updates are applied. The only way to reliably identify your version is looking to the package manager version using `apt-cache policy` or other tool:

```
➜  ~  apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1f-1
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1f-1 0
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
➜  ~  dpkg -l openssl
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  openssl        1.0.1f-1     i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cr
➜  ~
```

As you can see, my version of openssl is superior, through appears to be affected, since it's 1.0.1f, now if I check the changelogs:

```
➜  ~ apt-get changelog openssl
openssl (1.0.1f-1) unstable; urgency=high

  * New upstream version
    - Fix for TLS record tampering bug CVE-2013-4353
    - Drop the snapshot patch
  * update watch file to check for upstream signature and add upstream pgp key.
  * Drop conflicts against openssh since we now on a released version again.

 -- Kurt Roeckx <kurt@roeckx.be>  Mon, 06 Jan 2014 18:50:54 +0100
```

Yeah, I'm still affected. There's no reference to the CVE-2014-0160 in the changelog whatsoever. But, I'm not running any SSL/TSL service, so I can wait. I just don't have to generate SSL certificates using this version of OpenSSL. If I do, I just have to follow Gilles advice: take down the services, revoke the certificate, generate new ones.

Comment: Note: "apt-cache changelog" is not a valid command for me, but "aptitude changelog" is.

Comment: @ColinM sorry, was apt-get, not apt-cache, clipboard problem.