# Problem updating OpenSSL in 13.10 - How to diagnose or work around?

Tags: security, openssl

Following the instructions in the [existing question on the OpenSSL bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl), I've run apt-get update and upgrade, and  rebooted.

Now when I check the version, I do not have the version mentioned in the answers to the previous question "1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12"

```
>dpkg -s openssl
Version: 1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2

>openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it seems the correct patched version varies between releases/version.

http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/

quote:

```
Ubuntu 13.10:
libssl1.0.0 1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2

Ubuntu 12.10:
libssl1.0.0 1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.7

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:
libssl1.0.0 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12
```

Comment: Wow this is weird. Took me ages to realise it's patched. Why aren't the versions standardised.

Comment: By doing 'openssl version -a' you can see the build date 'built on: Mon Apr  7 20:33:19 UTC 2014'