# Problems with OpenSSL-Heartbleed in Ubuntu12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, apache2, openssl

This is a new question after I saw the answer at "[How to patch the Heartbleed bug (CVE-2014-0160) in OpenSSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-the-heartbleed-bug-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl/444829#444829)".

I have a vServer with Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Because of the Heartbleed-Bug in OpenSSL1.0.1 I upgraded all possible packages on my vServer. `dpkg -l | grep openssl` says:

```
ii  openssl    1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12    Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
```

I rebooted the vServer, created new certificates and rebooted the server again, but [the self test](http://possible.lv/tools/hb) says the server is vulnerable.

Where is my fault?

Comment: The output says that you have the path. The "selftest" algorithm could be wrong, not your system.

Comment: Have you updated `libssl1.0.0`? That's the actual library that other applications like apache2, nginx or postfix use.

Comment: I upgrade all packages on the server.

Comment: That *is answered* in the question you referenced. I have also provided a more detailed answer to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450076/openssl-remains-vulnerable-after-update-to-14-04