# Is Ubuntu 14.04 secure against heart bleed bug

Tags: openssl

I have read that there is a bug in SSL called heart bleed bug. Has Ubuntu 14.04 shipped along with this bug or has it been resolved in this release?

Comment: And see my answer to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450076/openssl-remains-vulnerable-after-update-to-14-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get this right [you're secure](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1f-1ubuntu2):

> openssl (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2) trusty; urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: side-channel attack on Montgomery ladder implementation
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0076.patch: add and use constant time swap in
>       crypto/bn/bn.h, crypto/bn/bn_lib.c, crypto/ec/ec2_mult.c,
>       util/libeay.num.
>   - CVE-2014-0076
> - SECURITY UPDATE: memory disclosure in TLS heartbeat extension
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0160.patch: use correct lengths in
>       ssl/d1_both.c, ssl/t1_lib.c.
>   - CVE-2014-0160
>
> -- Marc Deslauriers   Mon, 07 Apr 2014 15:37:53 -0400

Answer (score 3):

Yes, provided you've installed the latest updates. The latest version of openssl in the 14.04 repositories is 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2. You can check that you're running that version by opening a terminal and running:
`apt-cache show openssl | grep Version`