# Patch OpenSSL CVE-2014-0160 on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: security, openssl

NO, this is not a duplicate of [How to patch the Heartbleed bug (CVE-2014-0160) in OpenSSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl). So, read on.

I am seeing conflicting information with respect to Ubuntu 12.04:

1. The [Heartbleed page](http://heartbleed.com/) claims Ubuntu 12.04 to be affected and needs to be patched with 1.0.1g
2. The [Ubuntu Security Notice USN-2165-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/) claims that version `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12` for the package `libssl1.0.0` should fix the issue on Ubuntu 12.04.

Now I do have these packages installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep ssl
ii  libssl1.0.0                      1.0.1-4ubuntu5.10                 SSL shared libraries
ii  openssl                          1.0.1-4ubuntu5.10                 Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools

# lsb_release  -a | grep -i description
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
```

So, If I consider above two points, I am not sure which one is true.

Besides, [this Heartbleed test page](http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/) says that my machine is vulnerable.

Has anyone yet been able to fix this issue successfully on Ubuntu 12.04? If yes, then could you provide me the steps you have taken?

Comment: See also https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 for the fixed version Changelog

Comment: shouldn't the openssl version be 1.0.1g which contains the fix for CVE-2014-0160 as per the changelog on OpenSSL.org

Comment: @Greco, correct me if I am wrong. The version `1.0.1g` shows up only if it is installed via source. If it installed via the `apt-get`, it shows `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12`. Please refer: http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to patch the Heartbleed bug (CVE-2014-0160) in OpenSSL?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-the-heartbleed-bug-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you update? If Ubuntu says you need 5.12, and that heartbleed site says you're vulnerable, what's the problem?

I have the following installed, which was updated yesterday or today on my machine.

```
ii  openssl                                  1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12
```

Answer (score 20):

Ubuntu has released a patch, you just need to update and upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To check if you have the latest and patched version, run:

```
openssl version -a

OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Apr  7 20:33:19 UTC 2014
platform: debian-amd64
```

Check the "built on:" item, it should be build Apr 7.

Comment: +1...thanks for the `-a` option. It give much more information. All this time I was simply running `openssl version`.

Comment: Your welcome, I learned it yesterday ;)

Comment: Perfect Answer. Was unsure that I could just use `apt-get` to do everything.

Comment: when i run `dpkg`, I'm told I have `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12` of the library - but when I run `openssl version -a` it reports as `OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012` with a build date of `Mon Apr  7 20:33:29 UTC 2014` - is it the build date that is important?

Comment: @HorusKol, your configuration is good. It is same at my end as well and that indeed is a desirable one. So nothing to worry.