# I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as live desktop CD for banking am I subject to the Heartbleed bug?

Tags: apache2, openssl

I am not running any Apache or any thing that triggers ssl libray, so is there a service in Ubuntu that runs Open ssl by default?

**So, I am just booting live session for internet browser. Am I safe?**

Comment: Why are you booting livecd, not internal drive?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No, you're not.

The heartbleed bug has been exhaustively analyzed elsewhere but the point is that it affects *servers*. You don't care about it with respect to your computer unless you run a server on it. This does *not* mean that you're safe however.

The danger is that your bank is affected by it, you should certainly change your passwords etc. The fact that you use a Live CD for banking purposes is completely irrelevant, the bug is server side, so you are as affected by it as anyone else.

Comment: Not completely correct - if you are using a vulnerable OpenSSL then a malicious server can extract information from your browser's memory. As @Mark mentioned in his answer, Firefox on Ubuntu uses NSS and not OpenSSL, though (as does Chromium), so it is safe (although other applications may not be).

Answer (score 3):

I'll have to contradict both the other answers.  If you are booting a livecd for Internet browsing and only browsing, *your computer* is safe from being attacked.  The Heartbleed bug can be used to attack clients who connect to a hostile server just like hostile clients can use it to attack a server.  However, the only client you're using is (presumably) Firefox, which uses NSS instead of OpenSSL and is thus immune.

However, **you** are not safe.  If any servers you visit is vulnerable, any information you send to that server can be read by an attacker.

Comment: Ironically, you may not be *completely* safe if you have an older livecd that doesn't have the latest updates. (Firefox or others could be older, unsecure versions).

Answer (score 1):

Before using the internet to do banking just run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libcurl3 openssl python-openssl ssl-cert firefox firefox-globalmenu
```

If you are really strapped for memory, this can be done first thing after the live system boots to maximize efficiency. Firefox should probably be updated anyway if you are banking and what-not to catch up with all the **other** security updates.

I found these applications by running

```
dpkg -l | grep OpenSSL
```

on a 12.04.4 Ubuntu live cd. There may be more using SSL that I've missed here, I did not search any further.

Comment: If you really want to know, run the masstest [https://github.com/musalbas/heartbleed-masstest](https://github.com/musalbas/heartbleed-masstest). By altering the "top-1m.csv" list of websites, you can check any URL you place on the list.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you are running any version of OpenSSL from 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f. Ubuntu 12.04.4 ships with OpenSSL 1.0.1, so yes, you are subject to the bug, NO you are not safe.

If you can update to OpenSSL 1.0.1g you are safe, but as of right now, 12.04.4 ships with a susceptible version, 1.0.1.

There is a list, and a better explanation on [the official Heartbleed site](http://www.heartbleed.com). Go check it out. Also, there is a question, [How to patch the Heartbleed bug (CVE-2014-0160) in OpenSSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-the-heartbleed-bug-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl), on the site. Check those out and you should be set.